# Saving a bitmap in emf format using memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to save a bitmap image using memory stream object in emf format. When I used save method, it throws following exception:[image]

Code:

```
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath("Stacking.Png"));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Emf);
```

Please explain me what is causing this error and how can I save the file in emf format?

Thanks and regards,
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple workaround for this. I used the following code:

```
        image.Save(Server.MapPath(FileName));
        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(Filename)));
        System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(Filename));
```

This helped me downloading the image in emf file using memory stream object but still I have to save the image temporarily in server.

Thanks for the reply guys.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, the EMF is a [vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) type of an image, and PNG, BMP, GIF etc are the **raster** ones.

One cannot simply convert raster into the vector unless you are using some extra specified software for this.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the png file in bitmap to emf format using c#?

Comment: Yes, if you create your own converter. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(image_tracing)).

Answer (score -1):

```
string image = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\1.43-Branches-and-Birds.png")); 

byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
Stream ImageStream = new MemoryStream(encodedDataAsBytes);
string UniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n") + ".bmp";
string UniqueFileName = userregistration.Id + "_abcd.png";
string uploadFolderPath = "~/ProfileImage/";
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadFolderPath);

System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ImageStream);
img.Save(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "ProfileImage\\" + UniqueFileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Emf);*/
```

Comment: Also, it's always good to put some explanation along the code to show the OP what was causing the error, bug, ....